# Table of Contents on Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
 \tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\bf Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearpage
%
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Table} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearpage
%
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{\par\nobreak\textbf{{\scshape Figure} \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}
\clearpage
%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf Acronym}
 \section*{Acronym}
```

[image]

Here I want the **'Acronym'** line to be like **'List of Tables'** and **'List of Figures'**. (Changing indentation and remove the dotted line)

How could I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped a lot if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed your problem. For example, how did you get the "List of Figures" shown in the ToC?

Perhaps trying

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf Acronym}
```

instead of adding it as a section will help.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.